# How to determine which Listview or Adapter is using an OnClick Method. Android

Tags: java, android, listview, android-adapter

I want to use an OnClick method for multiple ListViews and Adapters. Inside my code I would like to check which adapter or listview click instantiated the method call. Here is what I was trying to no avail

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    if(parent==listView1.getParent()) {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple `ListView`, you need to know which `ListView` is being clicked. So you need to check it first.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    switch (parent.getId()) {
        case R.id.listView1:       // this is ID in XML layout
            // do action for ListView 1;
            break;
        case R.id.listView2:       // this is ID in XML layout
            // do action for ListView 2;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    String value = list.get(position);
    //Action when clicked
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, value, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```